# Problems with getting emails with JavaMail 1.6.2 from OutLook through IMAP

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I developed a code last November that basically connects to my OutLook and downloads attachments from a specified email address which haven't been read yet by the program. My code was fully functioning (no bugs, did what I wanted it to do) and everything seemed fine.

I last checked my code in early December, late November. However, after returning from vacations in January, I ran my code again and this time it didn't work. I was able to log into OutLook no problems, but my code wasn't able to fetch any emails. I tried removing all my search terms and just fetch emails generally, but it wasn't able to do that either. I have attached my code below, but I am at a loss as to how I can fix this problem, or what even is the problem:

---

```
            EmailAttachmentReceiver receiver = new EmailAttachmentReceiver();
            receiver.setSaveDirectory(dir); //directory to save files in for later
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
            Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties);
            try {
                Store store = session.getStore("imap");
                store.connect(host, userName, password); //host: "outlook.office365.com"
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MajorMain.EmailStatus.setText("Connected to email");
                    }
                });
                IMAPFolder folderInbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
                folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                
                //my 2 search terms
                SearchTerm searchTermEmail = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("xxx@xxx.com")); //just removed email address for security
                SearchTerm seachTermSeen = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
                
                //only updates the gui I have running
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MajorMain.EmailStatus.setText("Finding emails");
                    }
                });
                //
                
                SearchTerm searchTerm = new AndTerm(searchTermEmail, seachTermSeen);
                Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.search(searchTerm);
                System.err.println("hi"); // doesnt reach this line anymore.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be advised to always provide a complete example reproducing the problem, not just a snippet out of context. For instance, there are no imports by which other people could identify the classes you use. You also did not mention what was not working and what kind of error messages you might have seen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

turns out  i needed com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0.

Comment: That answer does not explain the reason and therefore helps nobody. If the code and Java version have not changed, a new dependency should not be necessary. My guess is, that you upgraded from an older version to JRE 11+ where [Jakarta Activation (JAF; formerly JavaBeans Activation Framework)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Activation) is no longer part of Java SE.